# Passing Information from a Windows Service to a Web Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web, service

I have developed a Windows Service that runs every 10 seconds and collects real time data from a couple of web services. That data is then collated and sent in an xml file to a web site outside my system.

I now have a requirement to display this real-time data in an internal web page, which can be viewed by user in our company.

One option would be to write this data to a database table and access it from the web page. However as the data is real time statistics, there is no requirement to store the data in the long term.

Is there a good way to pass the data to the web page so that it can be displayed to the users that does not require multiple calls to the database and put a strain on the network?

Any thoughts or ideas would be welcome.

Comment: SignalR should be a good approach :)

Comment: SignalR would be nice. If you're looking for a less sophisticated method, you might consider dropping the xml file in a directory on the web server and using that as a data source for your page, and then simply reloading the page every 10 seconds with javascript. Whenever the server sends the data, overwrite the file.